# compute in 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'

Tags: dart, flutter

In my application, I need to do heavy processing (generating thumbnails of 3000 images).
When I am doing the processing in an async method, App UI freezes. I tried [Isolate](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html). It is working but looks over complicated. I found there is functionality **compute() in  'package:flutter/foundation.dart'** which is much simpler. When I launched 1000 compute at the same time, it causes an App crash.

Is there any limit for parallel **compute()** execution?
Or is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Any error message? It's probably not a good idea to run 1000 `compute()` at the same time. `compute()` also just creates an isolate, it's just a wrapper method over normal isolate creation. I guess your app just runs out of memory.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pool should do what you want